# UIImage setImage not work, sometimes

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a class variable `imageView` of class `UIImageView` and a button.
The array of images is loaded from the Gallery by using Assets.
When the loading of all images is done, I show the first image:

```
 - (void)showImage
{

if ([images count] > 0)
    [self.imageView setImage:[images objectAtIndex:0]];
currentPage = 0;
    }
```

Everything is good so far,

But when I tap the button with following action:

```
- (IBAction)buttonNext:(id)sender {

 NSLog(@"images array   %@", images );
if (currentPage <   [images count]-1)
  {
   NSLog(@"next currentPage %d %d %@",currentPage, [images count],[images objectAtIndex:currentPage])
    currentPage++;
    [self.imageView setImage:[images objectAtIndex:currentPage]];
  }
}
```

no image replacement takes place. The `imageView` stucks the previous image.
I debugged the array of images:

```
 images array   (
  "<UIImage: 0xb38cec0>",
  "<UIImage: 0xb0f8280>",
  "<UIImage: 0xb063360>",
  "<UIImage: 0xb0660a0>"
)
```

**EDIT**
The code which loads the images:

```
-(void)loadImage:(NSString*)url
{
  ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

  ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
  {


    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        UIImage *largeImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        CGSize size=CGSizeMake(400, 500);//set the width and height
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        [largeImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
         UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        //here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [images addObject:newImage];

        if  ([images count] == [pages count])
            [self showImage];

    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Can't get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};

NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];


 [assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl
                resultBlock:resultblock
               failureBlock:failureblock];

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

for(NSDictionary* a in pages)
    {
        if ([a objectForKey:@"iospath"] != nil)
            [self loadImage:[document objectForKey:@"iospath"]];
    }
```

`pages` is an array loaded in viewDidLoad. The images are there. Why I can not show'em?
Regards

Comment: Show code where u fill array 'images'

Comment: I added the code which loads the images array

Comment: Have you checked that is compiler went inside if loop?

Comment: @wesley which one? That one in buttonNext is ok. When I press it, I log a test sentence...

Comment: in buttonNext method where you set next Image

Comment: You are running same code for six time so it may loading same image each time.

Comment: @wesley It is in the array

Comment: @CRDave Sorry, I miscopied the code. See the edit.

Comment: may i know where you initiate the images array?

Comment: @wesley In viewDidLoad I have  images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: last try, log the currentPage values before/after you incremented in buttonNext method

Comment: @wesley Done. The currentPage increments/decrements correctly.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the images loaded...